# Java pass variable into mapped DTO method?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, dto

I have Spring Boot Application with implementation containing methods with following functions. The implementation uses 2 DTO's to bind data with. Is there an appropriate way how I could pass value from ***JAY*** to value where '***10.00***' is hardcoded? I have main issue with '***this::convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO***' is it possible to pass a parameter in this expression?

I have used [Java DTO Object search mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287209/java-dto-object-search-mechanism) for insipration

If I try to add a parameter within code snipped below the this::convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO complains about bad return type

```
convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO(final Profile theProfile, Double JAY)
```

**Implementation**

```
 @Override
    public Double testThisParam(Double profileCredit) {
        Double JAY = profileCredit;
        log.error(String.valueOf(JAY));
        return JAY;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<ProfileCreditDTO> findProfileBySelectedParameters(String username, Pageable pageable) {

        Page<Profile> searchData= profileRepository.findByAllParameters(username, pageable);

        Page<ProfileCreditDTO> searchProfileData=null;

        if(searchData != null)
            searchProfileData=searchData.map(this::convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO);
        return searchProfileData;
    }        

public ProfileCreditDTO convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO(final Profile theProfile ){

        if(theProfile == null)
            return null;
        ProfileCreditDTO theDTO= new ProfileCreditDTO();

        theDTO.setProfile(theProfile);

        CreditDTO theCreditDto = profileCreditClient.findClientByProfileId(theProfile.getId(), 10.00);

        if(theCreditDto != null )
            theDTO.setCredit(theCreditDto);
        else {

            return null;

        }

        return theDTO;
    }
```

Comment: you might use lambda expression and pass whatever parameter you want to pass. Like- **map(profile -> convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO(profile, otherParameters).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pass more parameters to a lambda expression

```java
searchProfileData = searchData.map(x -> this.convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO(x, JAY));
```

As a side note, if you want to keep the functional call simple with `this::` style, you can create a data object to carry in your required parameters

```java
class MyObject {
    Profile theProfile;
    Double JAY;
    // public constructor with parameters
}

// then construct and use this

MyObject o = new MyObject(theProfile, testThisParam(...));

// and then change parameter of target method

convertProfileToProfileCreditDTO(MyObject myObject) ...
```